How to add a Python list to the end of a column in Excel that already has values in it?
I'm currently trying to write a program that appends values to a list and then adds these values to a column in an Excel data sheet. Each time I run the program, I hope to add more values to the end of this same column.
So I'm unsure how to go about this and have not had much success with other answers I've found online.

Please show what you've tried so far.

You can use Openpyxl's append method.
It will add values from a list or dictionary to the next unused row of a spreadsheet each time its run
For example given the code example below; 
Assume there is a header line on row 1 and row 2 is the first row with no values in any cells, with the list list_to_add each time the code is run append will insert the values 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' across row 2 i.e. Column A would have 'a', Column B would have 'b' and so on to Column D.
If you run the code again then the same values will be added by this time on row 3 that now being the next empty row.
From your description it seem you might want to add what is in the list down the column rather than across the row, i.e. the values 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' are added into say Column C only with 'a' on row 2, 'b' on row 3 and so on with 'd' ending up in row 5.
In this case you can loop the list and append each value. By default the values will go into Column A however you can pad the value so that the intervening rows have no values, or you can use a dictionary to set the Column to add the value to
from openpyxl import load_workbook


wb = load_workbook("Foo.xlsx")
ws = wb["Sheet1"]

list_to_add = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

### Add list across next unused row
ws.append(list_to_add)

### Add list down a column,  Column C used in this example
for value in list_to_add:
    # ws.append([None, None, value])  # Set values for Columns A & B as None and item to Column C
    ws.append({'C': value})  # Use dictionary to set the column to add to.


wb.save('foo_out.xlsx')

Note
'append' always adds starting at the next unused row which is basically the next row where all cells are None (some other cell artifacts can impact this determination). So if any other column extends past the last row of the column you want to add to, append will be adding to your desired column from the last row of the longest column (i.e. not the last row of the column you are appending to).
If the append to the next after last used row presents a problem due to other Column entries you can instead determine the last entry for the column you are adding to and loop and enter the value in that column using row/column settings
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook("foo.xlsx")
ws = wb["Sheet1"]

list_to_add = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

### Get the first unused row in Column C only (irrespective of other columns)
first_unused_row_c = max((cell.row for cell in ws['C'] if cell.value is not None))+1

### Add list down a column,  Column C used in this example. 
for c_row, value in enumerate(list_to_add, first_unused_row_c):
    """
    row is the enumerate count starting at first_unused_row_c and incrementing by 1 each loop
    column is fixed to value of 3 for Column C
    """
    ws.cell(row=c_row, column=3).value = value 


wb.save('foo_out.xlsx')

